# Objective C Iphone Development Distance Formula

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, ios4

Basically I need to calculate the distance between a point and a line (which has two known coordinates on) in XY axis
I got the algorithm but I don't know how to implement it into ObjC.

> Illustration: I have a line that pass
>   through two points A(100,300) and
>   B(200,100)
>
> m = (y-y1)/x(x-x1) = 300-100 / 100 -
>   200 = -2
>
> so:
>
> -2(x-x1) = (y-y1)
>
> Replace x and y we have:
>
> -2(100-x1) = 200 - y1 <=> -2x + y - 500 = 0 (Line equation that passes
>   through above 2 points)
>
> And the use another formula to
>   calculate the distance:
>
> ax + by + c / sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
>
> Replace the x and y of point I want to
>   calculate the distance to C(10,20)
>
> -2*1000 + 2000 - 500 / sqrt (100 + 400) = distance I wanna find

Simple this is it, but how do i do this in ObjC?

Okey this is the basically what I have done, and dont know how to continue:

```
float coordinateXStart;
float coordinateYStart;
float coordinateXEnd;
float coordinateYEnd;

coordinateXStart = [[strokesArray objectAtIndex:strokeNo] startX];
coordinateYStart = [[strokesArray objectAtIndex:strokeNo] startY];
coordinateXEnd = [[strokesArray objectAtIndex:strokeNo] endX];
coordinateYEnd = [[strokesArray objectAtIndex:strokeNo] endY];

//let's rock on distance formula from point to line
float m = (coordinateYEnd-coordinateYStart)/(coordinateXEnd-coordinateXStart);


enter code here
```

> Blockquote
>   Okey so I had m....but how to automate the calculation of a,b and c of ax + by + c of line equation?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place to get people to write your code for you!  What have you tried so far?  Which specific things are you having issues with?

Comment: I am sorry but I just don't have the idea how to write such code that comes out with the equation like ax + by + c. That's the reason i am asking how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You said `-2*1000 + 2000 - 500 / sqrt (100 + 400) = distance I wanna find`, and why not just write that in code?

The statement:

`distance = -2*1000 + 2000 - 500 / sqrt (100 + 400)`

Is perfectly valid C (fragment), and therefore Objective-C, just make sure you consume the [C Math library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/) first

Comment: The line and XY coordinates are just example. I need to use the same formula to calculate distance between random line and point. And I don't know how to make ObjC come up with the equation like ax + by + c = 0 (cant figure out how to find a,b and c)...though my answer is correct but the point is I want automation...

Comment: @SilverTsuki do you currently have some failed attempts you'd care to share? It would be easier to help you if I knew what attempts you taken to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

And after you know the C Math Library you should continue with [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163)